# SwiftUI Animation.spring - resizable Image and overlay not in sync

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to create a simple animation with SwiftUI where an Image inside a rounded rectangle with a red border is expanded and contracted repeatedly using the `repeatForever` animation. However, I am having trouble getting the border animation to be in sync with the Image animation when using `resizable()` modifier.

**NOTE: THIS IS ONLY REPRODUCABLE ON PHYSCIAL DEVICE**

Is it a bug in SwiftUI or am I misunderstanding something?

Here's my minimal example code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isExpanded: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack{
                Image(systemName: "pencil")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()

            }
            .frame(maxHeight: isExpanded ? 250 : 150)
            .padding(4)
            .overlay{

                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                        .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 8)
            }
            .onAppear{
                withAnimation(Animation.spring().repeatForever()){
                    isExpanded.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Look into Animatable, GeometryEffect or matched geometry effect they have the ability to be more accurate

Comment: Seems to work for me, on MacOS 13.4, Xcode 14.3, tested on real ios 16 devices (not Previews), and macCatalyst.
It could be different on older systems.

Comment: Weird. It looks like [this](https://imgur.com/a/UhLpJj0) on iPhone 13 Pro Max on iOS 16.0, with Xcode 14.1.

Comment: I don't get this at all. Looks good on an older iPhone 10 with ios 16.5 (just updated), using iMac with MacOS 13.4, Xcode 14.3 and target ios 16.3

Comment: try adding `.drawingGroup()` or `.compositingGroup()` to the inner VStack

Comment: It looks the same. If I add `.drawingGroup()` even the translation breaks, not just scale.